# Find solutions for $\lambda$ in this (diophantine?) equation?

Tags: diophantine-equations

I am interested in finding the solutions to the equation below:
$$\lambda = \frac{2^c+3b}{2^d-3^a}$$
$$\lambda, a, b, c, d \in \Bbb Z^+$$
$$d>a,c$$

**Edit**:
My original version was actually:
$$\frac{3^a(\lambda) + 3(3b+2^c)+2^d}{2^e}= \lambda$$
$$e>a,c,d$$

Furthermore, when looking at this original equation, it became apparent that this was actually:

$$\frac{3^a \lambda+3^a b +\sum_{i=o}^{a-1} 3^i 2^{j_i}}{2^c}=\lambda$$
Where $j_i \in \Bbb Z^+ < d-1$.
At this point, I am lost as to how I should attempt to solve this.

Are there solutions to the original equations, other than $1$ and $2$?

Can anyone find large solutions? ($a,b,c,d > 100$)?
I am only really interested in the large solutions.

Also, is there a technique to find solutions to this as I am really not sure how to go about this.

Comment: Is $\lambda\in\mathbb{Z}$? Something is missing here.

Comment: Sorry I was in a rush

Comment: If $c = 1$, $b = 4$, $d = 4$, and $a = 2$, then $\lambda = 2$. Is it really $3b$, or is it supposed to be $3^b$?

Comment: If you set $a = 1$, $d = 2$ you may pick $c$ and $b$ at will, which will result in a whole family of solutions, since then your equation reduces to:
$$
\lambda = \frac{2^c +3b}{4-3} = 2^c + 3b
$$

Comment: Should that be $3^b$ in the numerator?

Comment: Can this be solved where $d>a,c$?

Comment: @TheoBendit yes, it is $3b$

Comment: Refering to my comment above: choosing $d = 2$, $a =  1 = c$ you may still pick any $b$ you wish. Infact then $\lambda_b = 2 + 3b$.

Comment: @denklo That is indeed an answer however, that does not work for the case I am trying to find, as it is specific about the values of $a$ compared to $b$ and $c$. For instance, if $a=1$ then $3b + 2^c= 1$. This is because my question is the generalised version of the actual version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to describe the original problem before the generalisation, because in its current form without any restrictions the solution is straightforward.

The equation in positive integers $a,b,c,d,\lambda$
$$
\lambda = \frac{2^c + 3 b}{2^d - 3^a}
$$
can immediately be rewritten as
$$
3 b = \lambda 2^d - 2^c - \lambda 3^a
$$
So the only constraint on the integers (using $d>c$) we find is that $3 | \lambda 2^d - 2^c = 2^c (\lambda 2^{d-c} - 1)$. This results in either a solution with $\lambda \equiv 1~\text{mod}~3$ and $d-c \equiv 0~\text{mod}~2$ or $\lambda \equiv 2~\text{mod}~3$ and $d-c \equiv 1~\text{mod}~2$. There are no solutions with $\lambda$ being a multiple of 3.

For any choice of positive $a$,$c$, and $\lambda$ (not a multiple of 3) either all even or odd values of $d > \max\left(c,\frac{\log 3^a + 2^c/\lambda}{\log 2}\right)$ will be enough to guarantee an integer solution for $b$. Note that the constraint $d>a$ is automatically satisfied.

The solution for the original problem is more or less the same. Rewriting it gives that
$$
9 b = \lambda 2^e - 2^d - \lambda 3^a - 3 \times 2^c
$$
Assuming $a,c,d,e$ are positive the RHS needs to be a multiple of 3, hence $\lambda \equiv 1(\text{or } 2)\text{ mod }3$ and $e - d \equiv 0 (\text{or }1) \text{ mod } 2$.

It gets a little bit more complicated, because the RHS needs to be a multiple of 9. This means that for each of the 4 terms you need to determine what its remainder modulo 9 will be and how that is related to the values of $c,d,e$ modulo 6 whereas for $\lambda$ it is modulo 9. Also you need to distinguish the cases $a=1$ and $a \geq 2$. After this analysis, which is not too difficult but just many cases, you can choose any suitable combination of $a,c,d,e,\lambda$ with the only additional restriction that $e$ should be large enough to make $b$ positive.

Comment: Can you give an example $>10$ as I don't quite follow what you mean?

Comment: Sure: $a=17$, $c=23$, $\lambda=53$, then $d$ must be even and larger than $\max(23,26.9461..)$. For $d=28$ you find $b=2458087307$, for $d=30$ you get $b=16685166475$, etc.

Comment: Thanks for showing the solution to those two, but how could I go about the last one, as that is the one I am most interested in.

Comment: could you perhaps say something about the last equation I have added as it seem more complex than the others.

Comment: No it isn't more complex. A solution in the same style can be formulated, provided you understand the "solution" to the other problems. What is an issue, is that it stops being a clean problem, because you ask for solutions to an equation with many unknown variables that does not appear to lead anywhere. It looks very much like "let me ask a very complicated question". Why is this interesting? Where does this appear? What is the actual problem you like to solve? What are the restrictions? How much of it can you solve yourself and what is the problem you get stuck with?